# How can I compare a git bare repo HEAD to its work tree location

Tags: git, deployment

I've setup a bare repository on my server (/var/project.git) which is used for deployment. This repo has hooks to push out the code to the work tree location folder (/opt/api/project)

Now, we've gone ahead and made some changes to some files in /opt/api/project and are not sure what exact changes need to be made in the development environment.

> /opt/api/project/git status
> not a git repository
>
> /var/project.git/git status
> fatal : this operation must be run in a work tree

How can i compare the files on disk against the branch ?

Comment: It's quite unclear what your setup is, in particular what exactly the "hooks to push out the code to the work tree location folder" are doing, and whether "work tree" in this sentence actually means what it usually means in git terminology.  From the status output you posted, it seems that you are not "pushing" commits in the usual git sense, since the target is not a git repository.  With the given information, it is unlikely that anybody will be able to help you.

Comment: Trying a guess, you might be able to see the status using `git --git-dir=/var/project.git --work-dir=/opt/api/project status`.  If this works, you probably want to change your setup to be more convenient to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following to work with git the *usual* way:

- clone the git repository to a **new** directory within /var/ with `git clone`
- copy the changed sources to the **new directory** / local repository

This way, you would have a *normal* repository and you could use `git diff` to compare, `git commit` to commit or `git push` to push to the *bare repository*.